# Intel XDK web services: foursquare OAuth2

Tags: web-services, oauth-2.0, foursquare, intel-xdk

I am trying to add a foursquare web service to my app. I have done the OAuth2 authentication, and I got the access token. However, when I try to make a call for a web service like venue search, I keep getting the 401 Unauthorized error (error type: invalid authorization) as shown in the image.

I would very much appreciate it if someone helps me out.

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The token you're using is invalid. Try these steps (from Foursquare website). Note that there are 2 different methods, the first one being the preferred. For either method, make sure you have a redirect URI set in your app dashboard. (https://foursquare.com/developers/apps)

**Method #1 (Preferred)**

1. Direct users to:
   `https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate
   ?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
   &response_type=code
   &redirect_uri=YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI`

(generally done through a link or button)

2. If the user accepts, they will be redirected back to
   `https://YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI/?code=CODE`
3. Your server should exchange the code it got in step 2 for an access token. Make a request for:
   `https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token
   ?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
   &client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET
   &grant_type=authorization_code
   &redirect_uri=YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI
   &code=CODE`
4. The response will be JSON
   `{ access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN }`
5. Save this access token for this user in your database.

**Method #2**

1. Redirect users who wish to authenticate to
   `https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate
   ?client_id=CLIENT_ID
   &response_type=token
   &redirect_uri=YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI`
2. If a user accepts, they will be redirected back to
   `http://YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI/#access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`